# WMI Exception: "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used"

Tags: c#, winforms, com, wmi

I'm subscribing to a WMI event and receiving a "*COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used*" error when my application closes. This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573977/is-it-safe-to-call-an-rcw-from-a-finalizer), but it is quite different from my circumstances.

I am calling this code from my main thread:

```
string strComputer = @".";
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + strComputer + @"\root\wmi");
scope.Connect();

EventQuery query = new EventQuery("Select * from MSNdis_StatusMediaDisconnect");

ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);

watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived); // some function that does stuff when the event occurs.
watcher.Start();
```

The event is reported correctly. I suspect the problem is related to the way these objects are deallocated when my application closes. How do I prevent the error? Should I explicitly Dispose of the watcher, scope and query before my application closes?

Comment: Extremely old question, but since this is the first hit on COM RCW I would like to add that this often happens when you close a window before disposing of certain COM objects (as they depend implicitly on the Window handle). Adding some clean-up code in the `Window.OnClosing` event can solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, WMI is COM enabled, the exception is not entirely mysterious.  I suspect a race in the finalizer, try fixing it by calling the watcher's Stop() method before you let your program terminate.

Comment: First I overrode Dispose and tried to stop the watcher there, but the error happens before then, so after explicitly stopping the watcher, the error is solved! Thanks Hans!