# Can I reference / use COM objects in my finalizer?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, finalizer

I have a COM type (created using [tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) and a C# class that wraps this object.  I want to perform some clean up in the finalizer for my C# wrapper.  Following the guidelines [here](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2005/04/08/DGUpdateDisposeFinalizationAndResourceManagement.aspx) I might write something like this:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    private IMyComObject comObject;

    public MyClass()
    {
        comObject = new MyComObject();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Be tollerant of partially constructed instances
        if (comObject != null)
        {
            comObject.Cleanup();
            // Account for object being disposed twice
            comObject = null;
        }
    }

    // Other bits go here...
}
```

I know that finalizers can run in any order and so I should not attempt to use any object that implements a finalizer, however as far as I can tell tlbimp generated COM types don't implement a finalizer and so the above should be OK.

I haven't been able to find any official documentation on this however, so my question is **is it safe to reference and use COM objects in a finalizer?**

Comment: Did you try to invoke the GC at the beginning of your Dispose method?

Comment: They *do* implement a finalizer, that's how COM objects are released.  So, no, it isn't safe.

Comment: @HansPassant I used to think that but I can't find any documentation that states this and I also can't see a finalizer in the disassembly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to call an RCW from a finalizer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573977/is-it-safe-to-call-an-rcw-from-a-finalizer)

Comment: The finalizer exists on the RCW created by the CLR.  You can't see it.

Comment: Side note: Any unhandled exception thrown in finalizer code will force the CLR to immediatelly terminate your process, so make sure you understand exactly what exceptions can be thrown and handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I created a abstract com wrapper class, from which I derive all my com wrapper classes. It works very well. My original code is VB, since I need late binding (this was before C# introduced the `dynamic` type). The rest of my app is written in c#.

```
public abstract class ComWrapper : IDisposable
{
    protected internal object _comObject;
    protected ComWrapper(object comObject)
    {
        _comObject = comObject;
    }

    #region " IDisposable Support "

    private bool _disposed = false;

    protected virtual void FreeManagedObjects()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void FreeUnmanagedObjects()
    {
        ReleaseComObject(_comObject);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                FreeManagedObjects();
            }
            FreeUnmanagedObjects();
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected override void Finalize()
    {
        Dispose(false);
        base.Finalize();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static void ReleaseComObject(ref object o)
    {
        if ((o != null)) {
            try {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
            } catch {
            } finally {
                o = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static string ToDotNetString(object comString)
    {
        if (comString == null) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        string s = comString.ToString();
        ReleaseComObject(ref comString);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question (or compile)