# Writing the correct IDisposable implementation for classes with COM objects

Tags: c#, winforms, com, idisposable

I have a class that uses a .NET wrapper for a COM object and well it is giving me that infamous RCW error, so in my investigation I found that if I take out the Dispose() method from the finalizer of this class it will fix the RCW error so something is wrong for example the object is getting disposed but the registered events are still hanging around ... But just removing the Dispose() can't be the answer because then who is going to release the memory ? ( I ran a Memory profiler and confirmed that just removing the Dispose method causes like 20MB of extra Unmanaged Memory )

so something should be wrong with the way I am using the Dispose model.. here is what I have:

```
  private MyCOMobject theCOMobject = null;

    static SuppressFieldCntrlr()
    {
        new SomeCalss();
    }

    ~SuppressFieldCntrlr()
    {
       Dispose(false); 
    }



    private bool disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                theCOMobject.Dispose();
            }

            MethodFoo(false);

            disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the "RCW error"? RCW stands for Runtime Callable Wrapper, it's simply an automatically-generated .NET class that wraps a COM object. So an RCW is not an error, and I could not deduce what specific RCW-related error you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

For COM objects, you'll want to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`. The Marshal class is found in the namespace `System.Runtime.InteropServices`.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx).

Comment: I replaced Dispose(false) in the finalizer method with this Marshal method and still getting RCW.

Answer (score 2):

Unmanaged resources should be disposed outside of the `if(disposing)` part. In there only managed resources should be disposed.

In the COM wrapper:

```
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                //Dispose managed resource if any.                   
            }

            //Release the unmanaged resource.

            disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

and keep your implementation of the Dispose Pattern as is since the COM wrapper implements IDisposable.

I'm not sure about `ReleaseComObject`. It is [not allways recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/16/51355.aspx) apparently. There is also the [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx) method. Also have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573977/is-it-safe-to-call-an-rcw-from-a-finalizer) on how to wrap a COM object.

For detailed guidelines on how to implement the dispose pattern you can read this [blog entry](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae) by Joe Duffy. It is rather long but very helpful.

Comment: Ok Tried it...nop, now it even crashed faster than before with RCW error.