# Properly removing COM objects from memory

Tags: c#

I am creating a C# wrapper over the Acrobat SDK (yes, I know there are utilities out there already).  I'm importing an Adobe type library that was created in C/C++.  Perhaps this is obvious but I'm assuming this is unmanaged code.  Are **all** COM objects in the realm of unmanaged code? I ask because I'd like to implement a Dispose pattern to release all of the COM objects with Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(comObject).

Lastly, when is a Finalizer appropriate for unmanaged resources?  The Microsoft documentation talks about Files, Network Connections and other unmanaged resources.  It's a bit confusing for me because the Disposal pattern provided in the Microsoft documentation shows disposing of Unmanaged Resources in the Dispose method.

Would I call the Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject method in a Dispose or Finalizer? Thanks

UPDATE: There's some debate about whether to call ReleaseComObject vs FinalReleaseComObject.  I'm under the impression that FinalReleaseComObject is the better option.  As it turns out, FinalReleaseComObject calls ReleaseComObject itself in a loop until the reference count for that object is 0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject?view=net-5.0

Therefore, use the ReleaseComObject only if it is absolutely required. If you want to call this method to ensure that a COM component is released at a determined time, consider using the FinalReleaseComObject method instead. FinalReleaseComObject will release the underlying COM component regardless of how many times it has re-entered the CLR. The internal reference count of the RCW is incremented by one every time the COM component re-enters the CLR. Therefore, you could call the ReleaseComObject method in a loop until the value returned is zero. This achieves the same result as the FinalReleaseComObject method.

From reference source:

```
public static int FinalReleaseComObject (object o)
{
    while (ReleaseComObject (o) != 0) ;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the pattern I'm currently using.  I'm open to changing it based on the answer given.

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!this.disposedValue)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects)
            if(document != null)
            {
                document.Dispose();
            }
        }           
        // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override finalizer           
        if (this.application != null) {
            this.CloseContext();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(this.application);
        }
        // TODO: set large fields to null            
        this.disposedValue = true;
    }
}

// // TODO: override finalizer only if 'Dispose(bool disposing)' has code to free unmanaged resources
~AdobeContext()
{
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
    
    Dispose(disposing: false);
    Console.WriteLine("AdobeContext Finalizer run");
}

public void Dispose()
{
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in 'Dispose(bool disposing)' method
    Dispose(disposing: true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    Console.WriteLine("AdobeContext Dispose run");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Are all COM objects in the realm of unmanaged code?

No, you can write COM objects in .NET as well.

> release all of the COM objects with Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(comObject).

IMHO, using `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(comObject)` is not 100% safe. Imagine that the COM object is a Singleton (which is not likely) and runs in an EXE-Server (which is also not likely), you could destroy the COM object for all applications currently accessing it.

Just call [Marshal.ReleaseComObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject?view=net-5.0) and rely on the reference counting.

> when is a Finalizer appropriate for unmanaged resources?

Never. Really, that's why need [a proper use of the IDisposable pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface). (Highly recommended read!)

> Would I call the Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject method in a Dispose or Finalizer?

It is [not safe to make calls on an RCW on the finalizer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1575377/480982) unless some precautions were taken.

Comment: What is did was create a finalizer but it only calls Dispose(false).  In my Dispose method I called Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject() outside of the if(disposing) block.  So the finalizer is not directly calling Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject.  I noticed in my case when I failed to dispose, the finalizers ran and cleared up the memory of the Adobe document.  This would probably have issues in a multi-threaded scenario because a method must be thread safe to be called by a finalizer.  I remember running into this kind of issue in a multi-threaded service I created and I eliminated the finalizers.